# Why am I able to access Nodejs server through port 80 even though it's running on port 3000 and nginx is stopped

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, port-80

I am not very familiar with configuring a web server.  I have a node express server running on port 3000 on an AWS EC2 instance that is running Ubuntu 18.04.

In AWS management console, I have a rule allowing access to port 3000, so that I can access `mydomain.com:3000`.  No problem - that makes sense.

To enable access through `mydomain.com`, I installed Nginx and a very simple configuration using proxy_pass to pass along port 80 requests to port 3000:

```
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

       location / {
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header Host           $http_host;
               proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       }

}
```

However, when I stop Nginx (which I did as part of an unrelated attempt to move to https...more details on that if you need), I can still access `mydomain.com`.

Somehow, the node express server on port 3000 is being reached, even though traffic is coming in to port 80.  And Nginx is not running.

**What is happening?**

I checked `sudo iptables -L` and that does not appear to be the culprit:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Look at the iptables `nat` table.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - you are right on.  `iptables -L -t nat` showed `Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 3000`

Comment: @MichaelHampton Follow-up question: how is that entry likely to have made it into nat table?  I didn't do it manually.  Could it have been from attempting to allow https and installing certbot?

Comment: Nope, that's likely manually added as a result of trying to make a Node.js app answer on port 80 without using nginx. So it may have been there so long that you forgot about it.

Comment: Interesting, @MichaelHampton.  I'm reasonably confident I didn't do it manually, as today was the first time iptables came on my radar as I was trying to figure out what was going on.  In any case, if you're so inclined, I'm happy to accept your comment as answer if you post it